# Python multithreading module crashing without an error message

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

When I run my code, it just straight up doesn't do anything. The python interpreter just sits there and hangs until I close it. I don't even get an error message. What could be causing this? This is my code:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(x):
    return x

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
print(pool.map(worker, range(10)))
print (1)
```

Nothing is ever printed. It simply stops. How do I even begin to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am unsure why this doesn't work for you, I had a similar problem on my system. I overcame it by using `multiprocessing.Pipe`, which you can find here https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include the most important and relevant information contained in the link provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.